# Need alternate method for saxon.evaluate() as it is not supported by latest version of saxon-HE

Tags: xslt-1.0, saxon

Need alternate method for saxon.evaluate() as it is not supported by latest version of saxon-HE and also i am using xslt version ="2.0"..
if possible please let me know the working saxon.evaluate() function- so that will try to to create new java function and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, Saxon-HE aims for "minimal conformance" with the W3C specs: that is, strict conformance with all mandatory features of the spec, while optional features (including Saxon extensions) require Saxon-PE or higher.

For this reason neither `saxon:evaluate`, nor its XSLT 3.0 replacement, the `xsl:evaluate` instruction, are supported in Saxon-HE.

Some options available to you are:

- Use the old open-source Saxon-B 9.1 release (no longer supported, but still working)
- Implementing your own extension function using the "integrated extension functions" capability in Saxon-HE
- In some cases, the requirement that leads to wanting `saxon:evaluate` can be met by generating a stylesheet and then executing that stylesheet
- Upgrade to Saxon-PE.

Comment: Thanks @Michael Kay for info. can you please provide working example and reference for  your second point i.e.,"Implementing your own extension function using the "integrated extension functions" capability in Saxon-HE" 
Thanks in advance

Comment: No, I decide carefully what code I make available for free and what I ask people to pay for, and this falls into the second category. I have to earn a living somehow.

Comment: Can one please provide any free alternate for evaluate method with any other parser like XALAN or any other namespaces ..

Comment: please let me know the purpose of saxon:evaluate() function... will try to implement it using java by creating user defined funtion